# UIWebView: Error while loading URL

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, nsurl

I am trying to build an RSS reader for the Tom's Hardware website.

I have an error when I try to load an URL into an UIWebview from an RSS link.

Here'is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];

 if (self.url != nil) {
  NSURL *requestUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:self.url];
  NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:requestUrl];
  [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
 }
}
```

The url is setted by the parent controller.

When the URL comes directly from the RSS, I have an error in log:

[2234:207] Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=101 UserInfo=0x3a6a240 "Operation could not be completed. (WebKitErrorDomain error 101.)"

When I set manually the URL with the same URL like below, it work !

```
self.url = @"http://www.presence-pc.com/tests/fraude-financiere-paget-macafee-23198/#xtor=RSS-12";
```

Here is an URL exemple: http://www.presence-pc.com/tests/fraude-financiere-paget-macafee-23198/#xtor=RSS-12. I have no idea about that problem.

I hope you can help me.

Best regards.

Comment: Can we get more info about the URL that's coming from RSS? What format does it take?

Comment: Check the URL with NSLog() and then copy it and paste it into Safari and see if it loads.

Comment: How are you declaring your `url` property?

Comment: The reason failed is that NSURL converts "#" to "%23", so you can not access the URL you pointed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem can be the anchor in your URL, a friend got the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guy, that'it, I have split the URL like this:

NSArray *split = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];

```
NSURL *requestUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[[split objectAtIndex:0] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

and now it work , thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I have this code which also triggers **error code 101**

```
 _request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:redirectUrl]];
            [editorWebView loadRequest:_request];
```

RedirectURL is an `NSString` which has this format **http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fnhome%2F**

I tried removing percent escapes using the method of `NSString` and it now works.

```
[redirectUrl stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```