# Why does UIWebView link click error out?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView (webview) with one link in it.  I have implemented UIWebViewDelegate for this class.  When I click the link, the page loads but I get an error.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
webview.delegate = self;
NSString *html = @"<html> \n"
"<head> \n"
"</head><body> \n"
"<p><b><a href='http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html'>click here</a></b></p> \n"
"</body> \n"
"</html>";
[webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"the error is: %@", error);
}
```

Error output is:

```
the error is: Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=101 UserInfo=0x3814410 "Operation could not be completed. (WebKitErrorDomain error 101.)"
```

However, this link works fine: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class

Any ideas on what the difference is?

Comment: You told us you had an error but didn't post the error? What's the error?

Comment: Sorry.  Just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

see [UIWebView: Error while loading URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528060/uiwebview-error-while-loading-url), it seems that the UIWebView is not capable of processing "strange characters", although I do not think that the _ is a strange character.

Comment: Once the url is split on the underscore, how do you give the updated url back to the uiwebview?

Comment: you can escape all characters, that give errors, in your url by using the stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding method

Comment: Thanks.  How can I get the page to automatically shrink so it fits the view?  Right now, once the page loads, it's huge so you can only see some of it.