# uiwebkit error 101

Tags: iphone, webkit

I have a search box which takes keywords in Hebrew and English and searches in wikipedia for the corresponding keywords.

If I type in English it works well but when I type in Hebrew it shows this error:

when I type Hebrew keyword  url looks like

> **http://he.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%95%D7%97%D7%93%3A%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A9&search=\u05db\u05db\u05db\u05db**

when I type English keyword url looks like

> **http://he.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%95%D7%97%D7%93%3A%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A9&search=iPhone**

Which maps to:

> Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=101 UserInfo=0xf6e950 "Operation could not be completed. (WebKitErrorDomain error 101.)"

is there any encoding technique that should be used to encode the URL???

Please enlighten me on this!!!!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: atleast tell me whats wrong in this question?????

Comment: whats wrong with this question folks

Comment: Is a browser giving you this error?  A server?  A phone?  A little birdie?  Can you change the links?  Have you tried changing the links?

Comment: How are you setting the URL? Can you provide a bit of the code?

Comment: Also take a look at this question, it might give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818341/why-does-uiwebview-link-click-error-out

Answer (score 33, accepted):

We can resolve this problem by using string encoding

```
NSString *encodedString=[siteUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *weburl = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
```

site url is

**http://he.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%95%D7%97%D7%93%3A%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A9&search=\u05db\u05db\u05db\u05db**

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had a space at the end of my url. i.e.

`https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%20` (Note **%20** at the end). I removed it and it worked flawlessly.

Hope it helps somebody.