# UIWebView not loading local webpage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsbundle

I have a super simple webpage that I just want to load a single local file. The file is /Resources/About.html

Here is my code:

```
NSString *urlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"About" withExtension:@"html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlPath];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `URLForResource:withExtension` returns an `NSURL`, not an `NSString`. You can use the result of that directly in your request.

```
NSURL *URL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"About" withExtension:@"html"];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL]];
```

Comment: Yours is working the best, but I am getting this error now: Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (WebKitErrorDomain error 101.)"

Comment: it might because of url encoding. check these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528060/uiwebview-error-while-loading-url and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028379/uiwebkit-error-101

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * urlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"About" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *content = [NSString urlPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView content baseURL:[NSURL urlPath]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet URLForResource is returning `nil` (Can you confirm that it is not?).  It will not perform a recursive search, and will fail if your "Resources" folder is an actual folder (blue in XCode) as opposed to a group (yellow in Xcode).  Try using the main bundle's `resourceURL` and appending your path to the end of it.